# Firebase Message Receive only on login Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using flutter firebase cloud messaging plug in and it is working fine. I want to receive the message only when user is logged in . I am receiving notification even after user is logged off.

I have following code . which runs even after user is logged off. How to stop following code when user is logged off.

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
       onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
         print("onMessage: $message");
         _showItemDialog(message);
       },
       onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
       onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
         print("onLaunch: $message");
         _navigateToItemDetail(message);
       },
       onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
         print("onResume: $message");
         _navigateToItemDetail(message);
       },
     );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just check if the user is logged in your app or not by checking the value of your shared preferences as soon as you receive the push notification,

```
 onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
         print("onMessage: $message");
         if (myPref.get('isLoggedin')){// here you check if user is logged in or not
         _showItemDialog(message);
           }
             else
              //do nothing
       },
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((firebaseUser){
 if(firebaseUser == null) { 
//signed out 
}
 else{ 
//signed in 
showMessage();
} });
```